# This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed

Tags: support, suggested-edit

Who actually reviews the edit? The actual creator of the post? Some Moderator? Who? Is there any reputation I need to reach, to be able to edit without requiring peer reviewing?

Answer (score 9):

You need [2000 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) to edit posts immediately. Anyone with the edit privilege can review a suggested edit, as can the author of the post (it's up to whoever acts first). Only users with [5000 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) can see a [list of pending suggested edits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits): before that, you can review those suggested edits you chance on.

For more information, see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on the main meta site.